# Python- Currency converter not real time

Tags: python

[image]

the main thing is to do what this image did
however im still stuck here [image]

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the currency input in a wrong way. Replace with this code:

```
amount = int(input("Please enter an amount to convert"))

if con=='a':
    print(amount,'converts to ',amount*0.57)
```

Also, to add more currency types, instead of typing everything, just put them in an array in this way:

```
currencies = [['CAD','GBP'],['CAD','USD'],['CAD','JPY'],['CAD','EUR']]
for i in range(len(currencies)):
    print(i+1,' ',currencies[i][0],' to' ,currencies[i][1])
    #change alphabet to integers
con = int(input("Please select the type of conversion"))
if con == 1:
    print(amount,' ',currencies[i-1][0], converts to ',currencies[i-1][1],amount*0.57)
```